# Consulta datos could firestore android java

Tags: java, android, firebase

estoy migrando desde mysql a firestore, me esta costando muchísimo ya que nunca use este tipo de servicios.

Estoy tratando de armar un objeto con datos extraídos de una base de datos firestore, para poder llenar un recyclerview.

El problema es que esta demorando mucho en cargar los datos y mostrarlos en la pantalla, acá pongo mi código para que por favor me puedan indicar si me estoy equivocando en algo.

```
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("tiendas")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<Tienda> TiendasPopulares = new ArrayList<>();
                        RecyclerView.Adapter<TiendasViewAdapter.TiendasViewViewHolder> TiendasPopularesAdapter;
                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager TiendasPopularesManager;
                        TiendasPopulares.clear();
                        RecyclerView TiendasPopularesRecycler = root.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerTiendasPopulares);
                        TiendasPopularesRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TiendasPopularesRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        TiendasPopularesManager = new LinearLayoutManager(root.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                        TiendasPopularesRecycler.setLayoutManager(TiendasPopularesManager);
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String id = document.getId();
                            String portada = document.getString("portada");
                            String logo = document.getString("logo");
                            String demora = document.getString("demora");
                            String costo_envios = document.getString("envios_costo");
                            String nombre = document.getString("nombre");
                            TiendasPopulares.add(new Tienda(id,nombre,portada,logo,demora,costo_envios));
                        }
                        TiendasPopularesAdapter = new TiendasViewAdapter(TiendasPopulares);
                        TiendasPopularesRecycler.setAdapter(TiendasPopularesAdapter);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.w("Tiendas", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Mi adapter:

```
class TiendasViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TiendasViewAdapter.TiendasViewViewHolder> {

public List<Tienda> items;

public static class TiendasViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public LinearLayout tienda;
    public FrameLayout portada,logo;
    public TextView nombre,data;




    public TiendasViewViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tienda = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tienda);
        portada = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.portada_tienda);
        logo = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.logo_tienda);
        nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre_tienda);
        data = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data_tienda);

    }
}

public TiendasViewAdapter(List<Tienda> items) {
    this.items = items;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public TiendasViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cartel_tienda, viewGroup, false);
    return new TiendasViewViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TiendasViewViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


    final int id = i;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    Bitmap myImage_Portada = getBitmapFromURL(items.get(id).getPortada());
    FrameLayout portada_layout= viewHolder.portada;
    Drawable dr_Portada = new BitmapDrawable(myImage_Portada);
    portada_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr_Portada);

    Bitmap myImage_logo = getBitmapFromURL(items.get(id).getLogo());
    FrameLayout logo_layout= viewHolder.logo;
    Drawable dr_logo = new BitmapDrawable(myImage_logo);
    logo_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr_logo);

    viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());

    String data = items.get(i).getDemora() + " - " + items.get(i).getEnvio_costo();
    viewHolder.data.setText(data);


}





public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Agregue el adapter para que alguno me pueda decir si es ahí que esta mi error, no entiendo por que es que demora tanto en mostrar el recycler en pantalla, demora aprox 10 segundos.
.
Probé también eliminando la carga de imágenes pensando que eso era lo que demoraba pero no, sigue demorando mucho por mas que no muestre imágenes

Answer (score 0):

esta consulta lo que hace es descargar todos los documentos de la colección ¨tiendas¨ y los va a mostrar recién cuando todos se hayan descargado

```
db.collection("tiendas").get()
```

Nunca hagas eso. Lo correcto es ponerle un limite o usar paginación

```
db.collection("tiendas").limit(20).get()
```

Si lo que necesitas es paginación, hay un adapter especial para eso que podes encontrar [acá](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md)

Comment: A perfecto entiendo, igual mi db tiene un solo registro añadido. No entiendo por qué demora tanto en agregarlo al adapter.

Comment: Puede haber algo mal con el adapter. Te recomiendo uttilizar uno de los que vienen en la librería FirebaseUI.